# How to use GitHub code navigation from browser?

Tags: github, code-navigation

I want to take advantage of GitHub's code navigation features on the browser but I am getting this error message at the top of the Python code:

> Code navigation is available for this repository but data for this commit does not exist.

When it works successfully it says:

> You're using code navigation to jump to definitions or references.

Could somebody help me understand what this message means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering [Code Navigation](https://github.blog/2019-11-13-universe-day-one/#navigation) was released in limited public beta for select repositories earlier this year, and available on Python repositories since last November, it is possible your repository (assuming it has commits) was not yet scanned, especially if it is fairly recent.

Plus, the [help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/navigating-code-on-github) mentions:

> Code navigation works for active branches.
> If the feature is enabled for you but you don't see links to the definitions of functions and methods, push to the branch and try again.

---

Q1 2022: precise code navigation is now also active for Java, Javascript and Typescript.

See [`github/roadmap` issue 371](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/371).

Answer (score 13):

Private Repositories are not currently being indexed for Code Navigation. Currently, Code Navigation indexing is being performed on Public Repositories and will be rolled out to Private Repositories over time.

Comment: What was your source for this answer? [This blog post](https://github.blog/2019-11-13-universe-day-one/#navigation) seems to disagree, which was posted _before_ your answer. "View the code tab on any **public or private** repository for the supported languages to try it out." Code Navigation isn't working for me, I'm trying to track down the current situation. Mine private repo was recently added, and so perhaps it isn't indexed yet... but I'd still like to learn more about the current status of this Github feature, and more specifically, this error message OP is asking about.

Answer (score 3):

**Amazing feature** :- Now you can open `VS code as a browser window`. For now it is on **Beta** version. Try below steps.

1. open the git repo you want.

[image]

2. Type `1s` in URL after ***github*** word like below.

[image]

3. After **hiting enter** you can see view like below. It is VS code

[image]

============**UPDATE**============

Any repo can open using browser window and it is exact same open with vs code that repo.

For use this feature `go to the repo and after press '.' (fullstop)`.

Now you can see **it will open like vs code interface**

Comment: I have tested the feature (at the time of writing this comment). It looks cool as VS on browser. Unfortunately, it does NOT help with code navigation which is the OP asking for. Also, it ONLY runs on public repositories.

Comment: Currently on GitHub *if you are logged in*, you can press `.` on your keyboard and it will open the repo in web-vscode, not sure it it helps with navigating or not though.