# Running into a basic issue about navigating code in github rep as clicking on a function-reference doesn't hightlight it or show definition

Tags: python, json, git, tensorflow, github

I was earlier able to browse the github repo at https://github.com/r9y9/Tacotron-2/blob/master/wavenet_vocoder/models/wavenet.py easily in browser, so that when I put cursor on top of jResidualConv1dGLU at Line84, it'd highlight and let me click on "Definition" and "References" of class `ResidualConv1dGLU`.

But I used the same repo in the same browser today, and it doesn't do anything. It doesn't highlight `ResidualConv1dGLU` or show links for Definition/References of it. It's as if it doesn't know that it's a class.

Is there some default setting needed to enable that? What am I missing?

PS: (It was working a few days ago, so I am not sure what changed in just a few days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What might have changed yesteraday (June 23, 2020) is "[Design updates to repositories and GitHub UI](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-06-23-design-updates-to-repositories-and-github-ui/)"

Try and make sure to clear the cache of your browser and reload everything.

That being said, when clicking on "Jump to", I see:

[image: Jump To]

"Code navigation not available for this commit", which is expected for a fork.
But I see the same issue on the original repository [`Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2`](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2).

Those repositories needs to be re-scanned by GitHub, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59260603/6309).

Comment: Possibly re-pushing the branch would be enough to trigger that scan.

Comment: Thanks for the potential explanation.